# Assigning to a variable which was moved in right side of expression

Tags: c++, c++14

Is this undefined behavior or not?

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = some_function();

p = some_other_function(std::move(p));
```

I've read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order but not found definitive answer there.

Comment: Why do you think it might be undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Quentin because `operator=` of `std::unique_ptr` is resetting pointer before moving there new value. I thought that part of this may execute before moving `p` in call to `some_other_function()`.

Comment: Which is the signature of `some_other_function` ? `some_other_function(std::unique_ptr<T>)`, or `some_other_function(std::unique_ptr<T>&&)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 What if first or if second variant?

Comment: First one is simpler as at moment of assignation `p` is empty, 
Second one allows to have self assignment: `p = std::move(p);` which is trickier.

Answer (score 4):

If you search for assignment then you will find rule 8 with only mentions the *built-in* assignment operator, and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) do [overload the assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D).

***But*** since the operator is overloaded, the statement

```
p = some_other_function(std::move(p));
```

is actually a *function call*:

```
p.operator=(some_other_function(std::move(p)));
```

which makes it part of rule 3 instead. And that makes it well-defined (because `std::move(p)` have to be done before `some_other_function` is called, and `some_other_function` have to finish before `p.operator=` is called).

Comment: But isn't `some_other_function` guaranteed to execute before `operator =`?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is defined.

`std::move(p)` is sequenced before the function call `some_other_function()`, therefore the assignment to `p` takes place after `std::move(p)` (it doesn't matter if the assignment operator is built-in or not because there are no side effects other than assigning `p`).

Comment: @vladon: Huh? It has [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) unless you mean it's not a built-in type? (Which doesn't affect anything here)

Answer (score 0):

The assignment portion of an assignment expression is always sequenced after evaluating the left and right hand sides, even if it's going to ultimately call a type's overloaded assignment operator (that is, assignment for a non built-in type):

See [expr.ass] (**Emphasis mine**)

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. [...] **In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
>   computation of the right and left operands**, and before the value computation of the assignment expression

So to answer your question, it is not undefined behavior. The entire right hand side of `p = some_other_function(std::move(p));` is evaluated first, and then the assignment of `p = <result>` happens. <strike>Since `p` was moved it's internal state is *valid but unspecified* ([defns.valid]) and assignment will bring the variable back into a specified state.</strike>

Comment: *"assignment will bring the variable back into a specified state"*: One possible case of OP is `p = std::move(p)`, the final state is valid, but I'm not sure it is specified.

Comment: @Jarod42: I suppose I can't cover every single class' impl of self assignment, so you're right. I assumed assignment always results in a specified state.