# using std::forward on the same argument in a loop

Tags: c++, c++20, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I know there are cases where using `std::forward` on the same argument in a loop is wrong because it may cause moving from a moved object, like so:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto applyTenTimes(T&& arg, auto&& f){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        f(std::forward<T>(arg));

    return arg; 
}
```

But, what about the case where the forwarded object gets assigned again? Like in this example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto applyTenTimes(T&& arg, auto&& f){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        arg = f(std::forward<T>(arg));

    return arg; 
}
```

Would this be valid? If yes, then why? Is it basically never creating a new object (when called with an rvalue) and just moving the `arg` into the function `f` and then gets moved back again into `arg` by RVO?

I tried looking at different StackOverflow questions, but none seemed to have what I was looking for!

Comment: Function parameters are not subjects of RVO: [Why is RVO disallowed when returning a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444485/why-is-rvo-disallowed-when-returning-a-parameter)

Comment: The spamming tags is a bad idea, especially when C++11 has nothing todo with mandatory RVO.

Comment: @273K ahh, I didn't know that. Does that affect the question though?

Comment: I thought std::forward was introduced in C++11.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [Assigning to a variable which was moved in right side of expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981850/assigning-to-a-variable-which-was-moved-in-right-side-of-expression)

Comment: That question doesn't involve forwarding a variable more than once @273K.

Comment: Be careful about the argument types. If `arg` is of lvalue reference type (let alone `const`, which the signature of the function would also accept), all sorts of bad things could happen, including but not limited to unexpectedly modifying a variable that the caller expects to be left unchanged, or making a copy in each iteration of the loop

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Interesting. How should I modify the code to avoid these sort of issues?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes that template will not compile for const arguments.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't. Should I just take a copy then?

Comment: @273K True, but that is only because of the re-assignment. The signature of the template would not reject a const argument

Comment: @عليالمطوع Depends on what you want to do. You can use a metaprogramming trick (or a c++20 concept) to limit the argument type to an rref, or optionally add a const& variant that would copy its argument and pass the copy into the rref variant...

Comment: Alright, thank you for the insight @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes!

Comment: Keep this in mind:  `std:string s{ "hello" }; s = std::move(s);` leaves `s` in an **unspecified but valid** state — **because of what** `operator=` does — suitable for *destruction* or *re-assignment*.  `std::cout << s << "\n";` afterwards is is **undefined behavior**.  So the question posed depends a lot on what `f` does.

Answer (score 2):

[std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), this will expand according to the input being an rvalue, or lvalue as follows.

```cpp
// for lvalue or moved lvalue
template <typename T>
auto applyTenTimes(T& arg, auto&& f){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        arg = f(arg);

    return arg; 
}

// for rvalue
template <typename T>
auto applyTenTimes(T arg, auto&& f){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        arg = f(std::move(arg));

    return arg; 
}
```

both functions are perfectly valid c++ code, and both involve calling the copy/move assignment operator, as [function parameters can't be copy-elided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444485/why-is-rvo-disallowed-when-returning-a-parameter).

Comment: What if a const variable was passed as `arg`?

Comment: @عليالمطوع the template won't compile, because `T` will be deduced as `const Y` and you can't call its copy assignment operator as the operator is not `const`.

Comment: So is taking a copy in this case the best solution?

Comment: @عليالمطوع if you don't want to modify the input you should take the input by value, if you are okay with modifying the input then the forwarding references version works okay, as no extra copies will be made, only a lot of moves.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. Thank you Ahmed!

Comment: Honestly, just do the 2nd.  The semantics are clearer and it makes sense regardless of lvalue/rvalueness.  Also add `[[nodiscard]]` to the return value.

Answer (score 2):

It's invalid. If you passed an rvalue and `f` happens to return the same reference it was given, you could end up with self-move-assignment, which classes are generally [not expected to handle correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13127455/2752075) (unlike self-copy-assignment).

I'm not entirely sure how to handle this. Something along the lines of:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(f(std::move(arg))), std::remove_reference_t<T> &&>)
    arg = auto(f(std::move(arg)));`.
else
    arg = f(std::move(arg));
```

Or, if you can't be bothered, simply `arg = f(arg)`.

Forwarding rather than moving `arg` doesn't make sense, since we don't need to preserve the old value, as we're going to overwrite it immediately anyway.

---

Also it's weird to pass `arg` by reference, but then to return by value.

I would suggest either passing by value and returning by value, or doing both by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Function `template`s are a form of overloading.  Overloading is having the same function name refer to more than one function.

The key to make overloading *sane* is to make every overload *have the same semantic meaning*.  Then the selection of which specific implementation, being not visible to the caller without extreme effort, is less likely to cause them to go insane or cause crazy bugs.

Your `applyTenTimes`, despite having the same implementation (up to the type parameter) doesn't really work that way.  If passed an lvalue, the first parameter is an in-out argument; if passed an rvalue, it is an in only parameter; in both cases, it is used as temporary swap space and is left in a strange state at the end of the operation.

A sane version of your template is:

```
template <typename T>
requires !std::is_reference_v<T>
[[nodiscard]] T applyTenTimes(T arg, auto&& f){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    arg = f(std::move(arg));

  return arg; 
}
```

or even just

```
[[nodiscard]] auto applyTenTimes(auto arg, auto&& f){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    arg = f(std::move(arg));

  return arg; 
}
```

this always takes `arg` by value, then uses it as a temporary internally, then returns the result.  It avoids a number of traps (like the risks of move self-assign, or const-assign-to).

The input argument is not used as swap space.  `f` does not get a reference parameter it thinks is meaningful, which is semantically accurate.

Comment: Your comment and code example is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Adam!